# Terme pour désigner le second prochain

Tags: demande-de-mot

Prenons les exemples de phrases suivantes :

> Je ne peux pas te rendre ton livre la prochaine fois qu'on se voit, mais je pourrais [la fois d'après]
>
> Il faut tourner non pas dans la prochaine rue à gauche, mais dans [celle d'après].

**Quels termes peut-on employer pour remplacer les parties de phrases entre crochets ?**

Outre les tournures comme "celle d'après/la prochaine/la deuxième" etc., il ne me semble pas connaître de mot atomique pour exprimer ce sens.

Par imitation de la construction "lendemain/surlendemain", je pensais que "surprochaine" aurait pu être un mot accepté, mais il ne semble pas que ce soit le cas.

Comment: « Le suivant / La suivante » peut-être ?

Comment: @Toto Ça me semblerait amener des confusions dans certains cas : par exemple, "je suis en vacances le mois suivant" est compris comme "je suis en vacances le mois prochain" et non comme "je suis en vacances le mois suivant le prochain mois"

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'il existe de mot pour ça, tout le monde utilise "celle d'après"

Comment: Le français est une langue vivante, donc qui évolue. Si un mot n'existe pas, il n'est pas du tout interdit de l'inventer, surtout si tout le monde va le comprendre facilement : pour ma part, j'adopte `la surprochaine fois`, que je trouve superbe !

Answer (score 2):

Je ne crois pas qu’il existe des mots pour cela dans la mesure où le nombre est connu. Pour la conduite on dira « la troisième à droite. ». On dit aussi couramment « la fois d’après. ». 
Nous utilisons en revanche (bien que de plus en plus rarement) « en huit » et « en quinze » pour les jours de la semaine qui suit ou de la suivante (http://villemin.gerard.free.fr/aHumanit/Langue/En_huit.htm)

De même, pour les dates toujours, on dit « le lendemain » et le « surlendemain » tout comme « hier » et « avant-hier ».

Enfin (en tout cas pour ce qui me concerne), ce type d’expression existe, mais quand on part de la fin :

- pénultième = avant-dernier
- antépénultième = avant-avant-dernier